# Plugin eclipse: How could I add an action in Right Click menu?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created my custom eclipse plugin. I want to add an action in Right Click menu (Right Click on the Project folder). This action will open an eclipse wizard. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: You use the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point to contribute to the appropriate menu.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 ,but since I'm a newbie with eclipse plugin, I can't find the right way to configure wizard inside the org.eclipse.ui.menus extension

Comment: The menu specifies a command declared with the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point. The command is handled by a handler declared with the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension point. The handler code opens the wizard.